# Chances of a binary message

Tags: probability

> A source emits a binary message, the chance of a $1$ appearing in the
> message is $0.6$ and the chance of a $0$ appearing is $0.4$.
>
> The input interprets $10\%$ of symbols as the wrong one.
>
> If the interpreter got the message "$101$" what is the chance that its
> the same message that was sent by the source?
>
> The answer should be $0.743$.

I tried to use the extended Bayes theory where i calculated the chance of the message being correct as $0.6*0.4*0.6*0.9$ and divided that number with the sum of all incomes and i got $0.75$ as a result which isn't in close enough to the result.

Comment: I tried to use the extended Bayes theory where i calculated the chance of the message being correct as 0.6*0.4*0.6*0.9 and divided that number with the sum of all incomes and i got 0.75 as a result which isn't in close enough to the result.

Comment: Ah no, think of it like sending a message from one computer to the other. While sending the message 10% of the symbols are wrong. The message is sent by the source and the interpreter doesn't know what message its supposed to get, it just interprets it. I should have translated the question better its " if the interpreter got the message "101" what is the chance that its the same message that was sent by the source."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Bayes' theorem, the required probability expression is

$$\scriptsize{\frac{0.6^2\times0.4\times0.9^3}{0.6^3\times0.9^2\times0.1+2\times0.6^2\times0.4\times0.9\times0.1^2+0.6^2\times0.4\times0.9^3+2\times0.6\times0.4^2\times0.9^2\times0.1+0.4^2\times0.6\times0.1^3}}$$

which is equal to $\frac{0.1050}{0.1413}=\small{0.7430}$

The denominator is the probability for the interpreter to read 101.

Example:

- First addend: input 111 with probability $0.6^3$ is read 101 with probability "True-False-True", say $0.9^2\times0.1$
- and so on...